# Comment traduire "undeploy" ?

Tags: traduction, informatique, terminologie

En informatique les verbes "deploy" et "undeploy" sont fréquemment utilisés en référence à l'installation/désinstallation d'un ensemble de programmes (e.g http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html).

Le premier se traduit par "deployer", mais qu'en est-il du second ? Existe-t-il un équivalent du verbe anglais "to undeploy" en français ?

Comment: Je ne vois pas bien le sens de "undeploy". Personnellement j'utilise régulièrement "déployer" quand on installe une version de l'application sur l'environnement du client. Mais quel serait le sens de "undeploy" ? Retirer une version ? Remettre la version précédente ?

Comment: "undeploy" serait l'opération inverse de "deploy", permettant de revenir à l'état initial.

Comment: A ma connaissance, undeploy est un néologisme qui n'est utilisé qu'en informatique, donc j'aurais tendance à utiliser désinstaller. Des verbes comme retirer ou rétracter pourraient peut-être convenir dans un autre domaine, mais il est difficile de faire une proposition sans le contexte.

Comment: @radouxju l'exemple que j'ai ajouté donne à peu près le contexte dans lequel je l'utilise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Version courte

> retirer/supprimer

## Définitions et nuances

Le concept de *deploy/undeploy* est proche d'*install/uninstall*, mais si les termes sont différents, c'est bien qu'il y a une nuance.

On parle généralement d'*install/uninstall* (FR : installation/désinstallation) lorsque l'on met en place un logiciel sur un ordinateur.

*Deploy/undeploy* est davantage lié à la mise à disposition d'une application sur un serveur : lors du déploiement d'une mise à jour, rien ne change sur l'ordinateur de l'utilisateur. Le client (souvent un navigateur web) se connectera à un serveur qui peut avoir changé un peu ou beaucoup.

Par exemple, les informaticiens parleront de « déployer la nouvelle version du site web », mais les utilisateurs constateront uniquement que « le site web a été mis à jour ». C'est la même chose lorsque Google (par exemple) commence à « déployer progressivement la nouvelle version de GMail », annonce souvent répercutée telle quelle dans la presse.

Qu'est-ce qu'*undeploy* ? Est-ce revenir à un état antécédent ? Non, ceci est souvent qualifié de *rollback* (FR : retour arrière).

*Undeploy* est réservé à ma connaissance aux serveurs d'applications : on a déployé une application (il est possible d'y accéder et de l'utiliser), mais on choisit de la retirer (l'URL retourne alors une erreur 404 ou 500).

La différence entre *rollback* et *undeploy* est nette : dans un cas, on a une ancienne version ; dans l'autre, on n'a plus rien.

## Comment traduire *undeploy* ?

Ainsi que [souligné par radouxju](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/15917/7224), *undeploy* est un néologisme de la langue anglaise qui n'est utilisé qu'en informatique et, même dans ce contexte, réservée à une utilisation bien spécifique. Ce mot n'est [pas défini sur Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undeploy).

radouxju a proposé « désinstallation » mais je crains que celui-ci ne prête à confusion avec *install/uninstall* et surtout rompe la symétrie qui existe entre ce concept et *deploy/undeploy*.

Si nous étions à la recherche d'un néologisme, par symétrie avec « installation/désinstallation », nous pourrions proposer l'horrible « dédéployer », mais cela ne semble guère judicieux.

radouxju propose également « **retirer** » et « rétracter ». Le premier est celui qui me vient le plus naturellement dans ce contexte. Lorsque l'on s'adresse à une équipe d'infrastructure, on peut aussi lui demander de « **supprimer** » une application.

## Note concernant l'utilisation du mot

Les serveurs d'applications (Glassfish dans le lien donné en exemple dans l'OP) offrent la possibilité de déployer ou retirer une application depuis l'interface d'administration. Je n'ai jamais vu cette fonctionnalité utilisée dans le monde professionnel (dans lequel je travaille depuis sept ans).

Par conséquent, je n'ai jamais rencontré de situation d'*undeploy* (ni d'ailleurs pendant mes études, hormis au cours de nos premiers TD sur les serveurs d'applications). Chaque application a le plus souvent son propre serveur. Si une application est obsolète et doit être mise à la retraite, on supprimera alors ce serveur.

Comment: Effectivement 'undeploy' n'est pas défini sur Wikitionary, mais 'undeployed' l'est en revanche: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undeployed

Comment: @fiddler J'ai choisi de ne pas en parler car la définition n'a aucun rapport (ce n'est pas ce qui a été retiré, mais ce qui n'a pas encore été déployé).

Answer (score 5):

[tl;dr](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tl;dr)

> Annuler le déploiement

---

*To undeploy* est un néologisme qui à émergé à la fin des années 1990 lors de l'apparition des premiers serveurs d'applications, WebObjects de Steve Jobs (à l'époque Next) d'abord suivi par ceux en Java de Netscape, Oracle et Sun Microsystems.

[image: ngram undeploy]

(source: [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undeploy&year_start=1980&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cundeploy%3B%2Cc0) )

On peut quand même observer quelques apparitions sporadiques plus anciennes dans le domaine scientifique ou militaire (ex: [rapport de la NASA sur Apollo 12 en 1970](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yA8_AQAAMAAJ&q=undeploy&dq=undeploy&hl=fr&sa=X) et [rapport du Sénat des États-Unis en 1969](https://books.google.fr/books?id=YBLGk2HdbRgC&q=undeploy&dq=undeploy&hl=fr&sa=X)).

Bien qu'absent des dictionnaires, sa compréhension ne pose aucun problème à un anglophone vu sa construction simple, préfixe très fréquent [*un-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/un-) suivi d'un verbe courant. Il est essentiellement utilisé dans un jargon informatique mais le terme n'est pas limité à un éditeur. Il a été et est toujours utilisé par tous les fournisseurs et utilisateurs de serveurs d'applications Java (Oracle, Netscape, BEA, Sun Microsystems, IBM, Apache, Red Hat, etc.) et correspond à une opération assez courante quand on travaille souvent avec des serveurs d'applications. Il se trouve que c'est mon cas depuis <s>seize ans</s> 1999.

*Undeploy* est l'opération inverse de *deploy* mais alors que la traduction de *deploy* en « déployer » est naturelle, il n'est pas possible de construire de manière analogue un mot français car il faudrait deux contraires successifs identiques (dé- dé- ployer) là ou l'anglais accole le préfixe d'origine germanique [un-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/un-) à un mot déjà préfixé lors de son importation par le préfixe de même sens mais d'origine latine [*dé-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9-) (qui a gardé sa forme latine [*dis-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dis-) en anglais).

Le verbe « Déployer » dispose de plusieurs antonymes, dont « ployer », « plier » et « replier » (ex: **déploiement** puis **repli** d'une armée). Seul ce dernier, « **repli** », apparaît parfois dans les interfaces en français de serveurs d'applications (ex: [tomcat](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/LocalStrings_fr.properties)) mais il n'est pas immédiatement compréhensible dans ce contexte.

On trouve aussi « **annuler le déploiement** » que je conseillerais à l'écrit car il à le mérite de bien décrire l'opération. On le rencontre à la fois dans la documentation des produits d'[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19502-01/821-1049/gejxq/index.html) (celle du produit Glassfish cité dans la question) et aussi d'un produit qui n'est pas un serveur d'application chez [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/Aa577579.aspx).

À l'oral, on utilise parfois le barbarisme « [**undéployer**](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1081140/java/serveurs-conteneurs-java-ee/tomcat/undeployer-proprement-application/) » mais plus généralement « **supprimer**, **enlever** » voire même « **virer** ».

Answer (score 1):

**Undeploy** signifie que quelquechose est desinstallee ou est mise sans operation. **Deploy**, pourtant, signifie le mise en action, le mise en operation  ou l'installation. Alors, vous pouvez utiliser les petites phrases comme "c'est desinstalle(e)" ou "est mis(e) sans operation". Ou **annulation de deploiment** peut etre utilise comme une phrase effective.